# New-AzureDeployment : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: azure

When trying to deploy new package to azure (PAAS) i get the following error:
New-AzureDeployment : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution, a little bit embarrassing. The server clock I'm deploying from was out of sync, 21 minutes behind the real time. 
Fixing the clock solved the problem.

Comment: You have just saved my life. Thank you!